# how to get the image from xml file?

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, byte

I have xml file in that i have

```
<Image>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD/7RguUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNA+0KUmVzb2x1dGlvbgAA</Image>
```

I want image on my simulator..
Is there any way to get it?
it is in byte code but i want byte code into image. 
Please give me reply with solution.

Comment: Do you know how it's encoded?  It looks like it might even be a relative path rather than raw data.

Comment: edit your question with that code in which your application is terminated

Comment: It would be nice if you also let these guys know that dataWithBase64EncodedString needs to be added in the form of a category and that it is not a native method of NSData.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert that nsstring   into base 64 encoding string and then

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:64encodedstr]];
```

Comment: this is a sample code... this is not suppose to work directly.... you need to decode your image string first and then it can be converted in nsdata and subsequently uiimage

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

or

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: it is in byte code. when i am trying to converted the data code into image then the simulator gets terminated...

Comment: what is the message in console?

Comment: There has to be a crash log. The reason for the crash will be printed on the console.